# 500 ошибка php authenticator memory_limit

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, steam-web-api

Делал аутентификацию для сайта, все прекрасно работает. С другого пк попробовал залогиниться, там сперва появлялась ошибка 500. По гуглил, сказали memory_limit увеличить. Окей, увеличил до 3GB. Теперь на том пк появляется такая вот ошибка(ошибка будет ниже). Понять что требуется поменять на 14 линии я не смог так как туго с PHP у меня.

**Ошибка:**

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/m/michael23/artifactgameplay.ru/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp.. on line 14

**Часть кода 14 строки:**

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits('avatar-' . $userId . '-' . $slug . '.jpg' , null, $image_contents );
```

**Весь код:**

```
function wpsap_upload_avatar($url, $userId, $slug){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    $image_contents = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $upload = wp_upload_bits('avatar-' . $userId . '-' . $slug . '.jpg' , null, $image_contents );

    return $upload['url'];
}

function wpsap_sync_steam_profile($currentSteamId, $wpUserId = false){
    global $wpsapConfig, $wpsapOptions;
    // SteamAPI call
    $apiUrl = file_get_contents( 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $wpsapConfig['apiKey'] . '&steamids=' . $currentSteamId ); 
    $json = json_decode($apiUrl, true);

    // Generate Meta Data
    foreach($wpsapOptions['metaFields'] as $name){
        if($name == 'realname'){
            $wpsapProfile['steam_realname'] = (isset($json['response']['players'][0]['realname'])) ? $json['response']['players'][0]['realname'] : $wpsapProfile['steam_personaname'];

        }else{
            $metaName = 'steam_'.$name;
            $wpsapProfile[$metaName] = $json['response']['players'][0][$name];

        }
    }
    $wpsapProfile['steam_uptodate'] = time();

    if(!empty($wpsapProfile)){
        return $wpsapProfile;

    }else{
        return false;

    }
}

function wpsap_is_user_synced(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        $getUserMeta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'steam_steamid', true);
        if( !empty($getUserMeta) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}

function wpsap_button_login_url(){
    global $wpsapConfig;
    return $wpsapConfig['urlLogin'];
}

function wpsap_button_sync_url(){
    global $wpsapConfig;
    return $wpsapConfig['urlSync'];
}

function wpsap_button_logout_url(){
    global $wpsapConfig;
    return $wpsapConfig['urlLogout'];
}

function wpsap_button_login(){
    global $wpsapOptions;

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $wpsapButtonPopup = ($wpsapOptions['enablePopup']) ? 'id="wpsapButtonPopup"' : '';
        echo '<a ' . $wpsapButtonPopup . ' class="wpsapButtonLogin" href="' . wpsap_button_login_url() . '"><img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_01.png"></a>';
    }
}

function wpsap_button_sync(){
    global $wpsapOptions;

    if(is_user_logged_in()&& !wpsap_is_user_synced()){
        $wpsapButtonPopup = ($wpsapOptions['enablePopup']) ? 'id="wpsapButtonPopup"' : '';
        echo '<a ' . $wpsapButtonPopup . ' class="wpsapButtonSync" href="' . wpsap_button_sync_url() . '">Synchronize with Steam</a>';
    }
}

function wpsap_button_logout(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        echo '<a class="wpsapButtonLogout" href="' . wpsap_button_logout_url() . '">Logout</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас директива **allow-url-fopen** отключена подробности [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)
Вам нужно в php.ini включить её.

Comment: спасибо ошибка стала намного меньше(добавлю к теме новый скриншот). Еще хотелось бы уточнить как узнать вообще какие директивы должны быть включены а какие нет. Я просто в первые с этим сталкиваюсь.

Comment: @СеверинВладислав что вы там пытаетесь сделать? Почему это ошибка вышла?

Comment: там фатальная ошибка, так как происходит конвертация WP_Error в строку, нужно это поправить